# In Evince, don't see the option to add an annotation

Tags: pdf, evince

I'm trying to follow the instructions on https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/annotations.html.en to add annotations to a PDF document in Evince. However, I don't see separate "List" and "Add" tabs as in the documentation. This is what I see:

[image]

Do I perhaps have to install a plug-in to enable annotation?

Answer (score 3):

Press that clipboard thing on your screenshot (To the right of the magnifying glass). There you may add annotations.